# Website automation using Python

Tags: python

I m trying to automate a Web Application validation performed by my team.I have choosen Python as the language to do this, although my exp. with Python is very limited.I have done similar things in the past using Perl. Now the problem is that after posting the url of the website it directs to a logon page which is made in Javascript. From whatever little Python  I know, I believe scrapping/parsing website made in Javascript is not possible. I faced the same issue while doing this with Perl as well and wasn't able to proceed.

Any pointers or help in resolving the above issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: None of the Related links helped?

Comment: As Ignacio said, look at the related links. You will need a complete Javascript engine, so why not take a browser along?

Comment: Can you describe : what is exactly done with js ?
Is it only validation of inputs or what ?

Answer (score 2):

Spynner may help http://code.google.com/p/spynner/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look a [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). It's a firefox plugin that enables automation, but it also has a webdriver system where you can write automation scripts in various languages (including python), and a server execute the code in various browsers. I never tried the webdriver part myself, but that should do what you want.